# Was --killSignal flag removed from forever?

Tags: node.js, forever

When I use the killSignal flag when stopping a nodejs script with forever it ignores it. My command is (where index.js is the nodejs script):

```
forever --killSignal=SIGTERM stop index.js
```

Am I using the flag the wrong way? Can anyone get the killSignal flag to work? I'm using forever version 0.15.1, installed globally.

Comment: Per the [Forever ChangeLog](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), --killSignal was added in v0.11.0 / Thu, 10 Apr 2014, but never removed (as of 0.14.2 / Tue, 30 Jun 2015).  Q: Have you checked the ChangeLog on your (newer) version?  Q: What platform are you running on? Windows?  Linux?

Comment: My installation shows the same CHANGELOG as in the forever github and it doesn't mention removing it. Thanks for the changelog idea, I didn't think to check it before. I guess I'll open an issue about it in the forever project in github.

Comment: Opened this issue against forever: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/764

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a response from forever on Github. That flag should be used in the start command and not the stop command. E.g.:

```
forever --killSignal=SIGTERM start script.js
```

Then when you run stop, it will send the correct kill signal.